# Unable to install npx create-react-app@3.3.0 nucampsite

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-cli

As instructed by my school, I was trying to install "npx create-react-app@3.3.0 nucampsite" but it opens up visual studio code with the file `npm-cli.js`

I tried running the command from Visual Studio Code and I got this error message:

> ```
> C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:1
> npm/usr/bin/nodejs
> ^
>
> ReferenceError: npm is not defined
>    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:1:1)
>    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
>    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
>    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
>    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
>    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
> ```

On line 1 on Visual Studio Code this is what I have:

```
npm/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Comment: What is the result of that command: `node -v && npm -v && npx -v`?

Comment: so when i ran node -v its showing v12.18.2. when i ran the npm -v and npx-v 
C:\Users\Amraze Pirani\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:1
npm/usr/bin/nodejs
^

ReferenceError: npm is not defined
    at Object. I feel like its something related to the npm-cli.js file since i edited the first line of that file

Comment: basically its showing the same error message like i got above

Comment: Looks like you some how managed to install `node` but not `npm` and `npx`. Please try to reinstall `node`. After installation you should have `node` and `npm` and `npx`. 
PS: please use " ` " to highlight code parts of your message in comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I uninstalled node and npm and then reinstalled it back and it seemed to work perfectly! thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is correct, however - run this in your VS Code terminal:

```
npm --version
```

If it doesn't give you a version of npm, it means you don't have it installed, which is most likely the problem.

See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) page to install it.